# How to add and groupby distinct values?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by

I have a table such that

---

| PARTY | VOTES | DISTRICT |
| --- | --- | --- |
| ABC | 100 | NYC |
| BCD | 167 | NYC |
| XYZ | 209 | NYC |
| NFG | 308 | NYC |
| ABC | 103 | NJ |
| BCD | 120 | NJ |
| XYZ | 290 | NJ |
| NFG | 385 | NJ |

---

I want to group the votes for each party by district such that, party ABC will have its own data column with how many votes it got in each district. How do I go about doing it?

Answer (score 3):

Feel free to point out if I misunderstood your desired output.

You can use a `pivot` method:

```
df.pivot(columns = 'PARTY', index = 'DISTRICT')
```

Which gives you:

```
         VOTES
PARTY    ABC        BCD NFG XYZ
DISTRICT                
NJ       103        120 385 290
NYC      100        167 308 209
```

If you want numerical index (i.e. `DISTRICT` to be a column and not an index), you can then add `.reset_index()`.

Answer (score 2):

This:

```
df = df.groupby(by = ['PARTY', 'DISTRICT']).sum()
```

will give you a dataframe like this:

```
                VOTES
PARTY DISTRICT       
ABC   NJ          103
      NYC         100
BCD   NJ          120
      NYC         167
NFG   NJ          385
      NYC         308
XYZ   NJ          290
      NYC         209
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`pd.crosstab()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.crosstab.html), as follows:

```
pd.crosstab(index=df['DISTRICT'], columns=df['PARTY'], values=df['VOTES'], aggfunc='sum')
```

**Result:**

```
PARTY     ABC  BCD  NFG  XYZ
DISTRICT                    
NJ        103  120  385  290
NYC       100  167  308  209
```